# Pyinstaller no exe created, nothing in dist folder

Tags: anaconda, pyqt5, pyinstaller

When i try to run the pyinstall myFile.py, the build and dist folder are created, and the file myFIle.spec, but the dist folder is empty. In the shell I have a traceback at the end :

```
File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 838, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 784, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 31, in <module>
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 411, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 196, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/api.py", line 273, in assemble
    pylib_name = os.path.basename(bindepend.get_python_library_path())
  File "/home/indiana/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 146, in basename
    p = os.fspath(p)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Futhermore, I have a warning during the process :
 WARNING: Hidden import "PyQt5.sip" not found!
I'm more concern about the traceback ( since it seems it's not related to my code but more about the environment), so I wonder if somebody had seen this before and if someone has a kind of a solution.

Thanks in advance !